# Installing Xiki on Mac OS 10.10

Tags: osx-yosemite, xiki, osx-yosemite-beta

Has anyone successfully installed Xiki on Mac OS Yosemite? The developer's advice is that it is only compatible with Ruby 1.9.3, but Yosemite ships with 2.0.0, and I cannot successfully build 1.9.3 for Mac OS 10.10 (there are no pre-baked binaries, unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile for 10.9.3 ?

I got :

```
sudo gem install xiki --pre
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
ERROR:  Error installing xiki:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```